# Android: ListView make some specific Items unclickable

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` in which I have five Items. I want the first 3 items unclickable and on touching them, there should be no color change. And the last two Items should be clickable, which brings me to the next two activities. Please help me if someone has any code example or any helpful link to this problem. I have seen this method but don't know how and where to put this in class.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: are you using a custom adapter for your listview?

Comment: @babis yes I am using custome adapter

Comment: in the `getView()` method, you can check the position and adjust your layout... edit your question (add your adapter code) and I will tell you exactly

Comment: @babis are you there?

Comment: yes, please add the exact code you are using for your custom adapter

Comment: I want to say to post your above second comment in an answer I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the `getView()` method, you can check the position and adjust your layout...

Answer (score 4):

You have to override the isEnabled(int position) method in your adapter's class;

```
            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                if (positon > 3) {
                     return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you do not have header view, your isEnabled should look like:

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
   return position != 0 && position != 1 && position !=2;
}
```

`isEnabled()` is a method of the `Adapter` of the `ListView` that you have to overwrite. The documentation can be found [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

you need to return `true` in `areAllItemsEnabled()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled%28%29 to make `isEnabled()` being called

Answer (score 0):

isEnabled is a method of your adapter. But this solution will make all your list items unclickable. You need to check the position of your clicked item as well.